# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: admin/login.html

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

При попутке зайти в админку получаю ошибку:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/Site/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/Site/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/Site/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/Site/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/Site/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/Site/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/Site/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: admin/login.html
[26/Jan/2020 16:26:22] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78214
```

project-level urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

app-level urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import BlogListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '%3z-++zoz%6t7$qyw91(z$2*+4h0cw5ivr$q=9$e+5s)axb*zb'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS' : [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить `'APP_DIRS': True,` в `TEMPLATES`. Админка - это то же *приложение*. А вы отключили поиск темплейтов для этого приложения.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#configuration